# Why is entity-framework giving me an error about not existing data that exists

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using mvc5 and Entity Framework code-first migrations
I tried to seed table and i Got this error message:

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint 
"FK_dbo.Orders_dbo.Users_UserId". The conflict occurred in database 
"DbDemo.Models.DbbContext", table "dbo.Users", column 'Id'.
The statement has been terminated.
```

I know its saying that data must already exist in users table before seeding orders but `userid` in users is a primary key so I supposed that its automatically seeded because of its identity=true! so why did I get this error?

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNum { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    //ForeignKey from Items table for the composite key
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public int? ItemId { get; set; }
    public Item Item { get; set; }

    //ForeignKey from Users table
    public int? UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }

    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public int? TotalPrice { get; set; } //why did i put this field??!
}
```

This is the user seed migration:

```
public partial class UsersSeed : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        Sql("insert into Users (Name,Email,Password,PhoneNum,Location,Type) values ('Khaled Tahboub', 'khaledk.tahboub@gmail.com', 'abc@123', '0797504280', 'Amman', 'A')");
        Sql("insert into Users (Name,Email,Password,PhoneNum,Location,Type) values ('Muath Mustafa', 'muathmustafa@gmail.com', 'abc@123', '0797504280', 'Amman', 'A')");
        Sql("insert into Users (Name,Email,Password,PhoneNum,Location,Type) values ('John Doe', 'JohnDoe@gmail.com', 'abc@123', '0797504280', 'Amman', 'B')");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
    }
}
```

And this is the orders seed migration:

```
public partial class OrdersSeed : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        Sql("insert into Orders (UserId, ItemId, Quantity) values (1, 1, 1)");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: It's saying that you tried to insert an Order with a UserId that doesn't exist in the User table. Are you attempting to create an Order and a new User at the same time? Please show the code you are using to do the work.

Comment: i have just provided the code in the post

Comment: Is this Code-First? The User class is missing attributes defining Id as a key/identity, and you are also missing the attributes that would instruct entity framework that Orders.UserId is a FK to Users.Id.